# get_the_author_meta is not working in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

here is the code

```
<?php
/**
 * Display detail author of current post
 * Use in single post
 *
 * @since 1.0
 */
?>
<div class="post-author">
    <div class="author-img">
        <?php if( function_exists('get_simple_local_avatar') ){
            if( get_simple_local_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ){
                echo get_simple_local_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ), '100' );
            } else {
                echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'email' ), '100' );
            }
        } else {
            echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'email' ), '100' );
        }   
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="author-content">
        <h5><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></h5>
        <p><?php the_author_meta( 'description' ); ?></p
<br>
<?php


$bool=0;
if ( get_the_author_meta( 'user_url' ) )
{
    $bool = 1;
}
if ( get_the_author_meta( 'facebook' ) )
{
    $bool = 1;
}
if ( get_the_author_meta( 'twitter' ) )
{
    $bool = 1;
}
if ( get_the_author_meta( 'instagram' ) )
{
    $bool = 1;
}
if ( get_the_author_meta( 'pinterest' ) )
{
    $bool = 1;
}
if ( get_the_author_meta( 'tumblr' ) ) 
{
    $bool = 1;
}
if ( get_the_author_meta( 'email' ) && get_theme_mod( 'penci_post_author_email' ) )
{
    $bool = 1;
}

if($bool==1){

if (get_locale()=='ar') { ?>
        <h5 class="connect_with_ar">تواصل مع <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></h5>
        <br>
        <?php } else {?>
        <h5 class="connect_with">Connect With <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></h5>
        <br>

        <?php } } ?>
        <?php if ( get_the_author_meta( 'user_url' ) ) : ?>
            <a target="_blank" class="author-social" href="<?php the_author_meta( 'user_url'); ?>"><?php penci_fawesome_icon('fas fa-globe'); ?></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ( get_the_author_meta( 'facebook' ) ) : ?>
            <a target="_blank" class="author-social" href="http://facebook.com/<?php echo esc_attr( the_author_meta( 'facebook' ) ); ?>"><?php penci_fawesome_icon('fab fa-facebook-f'); ?></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ( get_the_author_meta( 'twitter' ) ) : ?>
            <a target="_blank" class="author-social" href="http://twitter.com/<?php echo esc_attr( the_author_meta( 'twitter' ) ); ?>"><?php penci_fawesome_icon('fab fa-twitter'); ?></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ( get_the_author_meta( 'instagram' ) ) : ?>
            <a target="_blank" class="author-social" href="http://instagram.com/<?php echo esc_attr( the_author_meta( 'instagram' ) ); ?>"><?php penci_fawesome_icon('fab fa-instagram'); ?></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ( get_the_author_meta( 'pinterest' ) ) : ?>
            <a target="_blank" class="author-social" href="http://pinterest.com/<?php echo esc_attr( the_author_meta( 'pinterest' ) ); ?>"><?php penci_fawesome_icon('fab fa-pinterest'); ?></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ( get_the_author_meta( 'tumblr' ) ) : ?>
            <a target="_blank" class="author-social" href="http://<?php echo esc_attr( the_author_meta( 'tumblr' ) ); ?>.tumblr.com/"><?php penci_fawesome_icon('fab fa-tumblr'); ?></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ( get_the_author_meta( 'email' ) && get_theme_mod( 'penci_post_author_email' ) ) : ?>
            <a class="author-social" href="mailto:<?php echo esc_attr( the_author_meta( 'email' ) ); ?>"><?php penci_fawesome_icon('fas fa-envelope'); ?></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

this code working for old users

[image]

but it does not work with new users

[image]

**EDIT**

all the plugins that I am using in the website are

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**EDIT 2**

[image]
[image]

Comment: The code is still working here with new and former users. Did you add a plugin related to the users (buddypress...) which could have overwritten those info?

Comment: I do not use buddypress and I have added screenshots of all the plugins that I am using to the post

Comment: @gael could you please check and let me know ?

Comment: That's quite a lot and it seems some of them are related to users but I don't know them all. I suggest you to install the Health Check & Troubleshooting plugin which will allow you to disable all plugins at once (only for you without closing the site for others) and then enable them one by one so that you can find which one may cause the problem https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/health-check/

Comment: @gael ok will use it and let you know

Comment: @gael I did install it and enable troubleshoot mode and disable all plugins and the problem is still happen in the users

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(isset($_GET['author_name'])){
    $curauth = get_user_by('slug', $author_name); 
 }
 else{
    $curauth = get_userdata(intval($author));
 }
```

Put this code in author.php. Then change the relevant places.
For example.

```
printf( wp_kses ( __( '<h1 class="page-title">%s</h1>', 'soledad' ), penci_allow_html() ), get_the_author() );
```

This line 61. Soledad theme -> author.php
You can put

```
$ curauth-> first_name instead of "get_the_author ()"

$curauth->user_email;
$curauth->first_name;
$curauth->last_name;
```

This way you can get all the user's variables.

Comment: Please don't promote your website or other content in answers. If you do that, you can be considered a [spammer](/help/promotion). You can add those links to your profile page if you want.